# How can I align a button with the legend in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Inside of a form I have a legend with a button:

```
<legend>Welcome Fictitious Employees
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
    </div>        
</legend>
```

The button aligns with the bottom border of the legend in IE and Firefox reasonably, while in Chrome the button renders over the line:

[image]

What can I do to align the bottom of the button with the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bootstrap so - this should be the same across all browser. Basically its because you were floating the button with the pull-right class.

```
<legend>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
        <p>Welcome Fictitious Employees</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSave">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div 
</legend>
```

To somewhat achieve a vertical alignment of the button and the paragraph use these css rules

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

the drawback is that the line-height is fixed so if you change the button padding or dimensions in general you will have again inconsistencies so have that in mind.

Comment: That's a pretty cool approach, but the text won't align to the bottom now:  https://i.imgur.com/ZyIS8Ks.png

I tried vertical-align on the <p> tag but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: the text is probably not aligning because a <p> tag has a margin in bottom by default. Try removing that, think it will then align :)

Comment: Ah, perfect.  Totally forgot about p margins.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad i helped! :)